# How to get different types of ICMP

Tags: tcpdump, wireshark, packet, icmp

I have a task on which I have spent a lot of time. I am not fluent in Linux, but I can manage basic things.

The task is to gather different types of ICMP packets. I can harvest them by tcpdump (which I prefer) or Wireshark.

I am able get the ICMP types of echo reply and echo request using ping, and time exceeded using tracepath or traceroute. Now, what I am trying to get is unreachable or timestamp or something else. I need two more types, however I don't know a way to produce.

I have tried pinging a nonexistent host or wrong port, and using tracepath the same way, but I am not getting anything.

Can someone advise me or tell me what commands I can use, and in which way, to obtain two more types of ICMP packets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate some of the ICMP unreachable variants with qualifiers to `iptables ... -j REJECT` on a separate target host. (Or a VM.) The possible qualifiers are `icmp-net-unreachable`, `icmp-host-unreachable`, `icmp-port-unreachable`, `icmp-proto-unreachable`, `icmp-net-prohibited`, `icmp-host-prohibited`, `icmp-admin-prohibited`, and `tcp-reset`.

For example:

```
iptables -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-admin-prohibited
```

Answer (score 2):

`icmpush` does what you need.

From `man icmpush`:

> icmpush is a tool that builds ICMP packets fully customized from command line.
>
> It supports the following ICMP error types:  Redirect, Source Quench, Time Exceeded, Destination Unreach and Parameter Problem.
>
> And the following ICMP information types: Address Mask Request, Timestamp, Information Request, Echo Request, Router Solicitation and Router Advertisement.

`icmpush` is licensed as GPLv2, is available packaged for debian (and probaly most other distros), and source code is available at http://www.securityfocus.com/data/tools/icmpush22.tar.gz